# Xlwings :how to read two comma sperated values in a single cell as a list and not as a float number?

Tags: python, xlwings

Using Xlwings how to read two comma sperated values in a single cell as a list and not as a float number ?
I am using:
`A1_val = sht.range('A1').value`

for example if  A1: 5,6 (two values 5 and 6 are in the cell A1 and are separated by comma)

the output should be a list [5,6] but it gives me a float number 5.6 any solutions for this in Xlwings?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to seperate your cell content of "A1" to a list.
Here is an example code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

cell_content = ws["A1"].value # Let's say A1 is "5,6".

list_of_strings = str(cell_content).split(",")
list_of_floats = [float(item) for item in list_of_strings]
print(list_of_floats)
# prints [5.0, 6.0]
```

If you prefer integer over float you have to use `int` instead of `float`.